# cURL --resolve in c#

Tags: c#, curl, .net-core

I'm trying to mimic curl's `--resolve` argument in C#. I'm going to do https requests to an SNI enabled server to make sure everything works before we're altering the DNS records. I'm currently on Windows so I could change the hosts file, but that's not a great solution.

I haven't dug down in the `System.Net.Http HttpClient` code yet, but if libcurl is down there I believe it's the `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` argument I need to set.

Running cURL in a new process doesn't seem to be platform independent.

Am I missing something in WebRequest or HttpClient? Is there a another, more flexible, lib out there with support for this?

Thanks

Comment: Note: since it's https it's not enough to set the HTTP Hosts header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use direct TcpClient for this. IIRC, HttpClient doesn't use libcurl at all.

What you can do however:

```
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

            string ipAddress = "216.58.204.46";
            ushort port = 443;

            client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port);

            using (SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, ((sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true)))
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("www.google.com");

                string headers = "GET https://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n";
                byte[] payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headers);
                sslStream.Write(payload);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                sslStream.Read(buffer);

                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

You can add your own ssl validations in there if you want aswell.

Giving you this answer as a temp fix, as I don't know how to do it with HttpClient aswell

---

You need to change the IPAddress, port, and the headers (as you need them). There should be some other framework for this, but since this is something that you probably need for personal tests, you shouldn't need anything complex.

Comment: If you change `AuthenticateAsClient` to use the domain instead of `ipAddress` this solution works. Otherwise the SNI flag will be the ip.

Comment: @MyGGaN I have just changed that in my answer. thanks for the input!